# How to programmatically parse and manipulate .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I'm looking for a way to programmatically parse my GitLab CI config (.gitlab-ci.yml).

It is extremely complex and consists of more than 20 individual yml file that are included via the [include](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/?query=include-keyword#include)-keyword. I'm also using [reference-tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#reference-tags) and [anchors](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#anchors) btw.

I'm looking to somehow load the entire "yaml" structure, so that all `include`s are resolved and I essenntially end up with on big "yaml" document. Obviously when I say "yaml", I mean that custom yaml-based format that GitLab CI uses.

My goal is to implement a custom property `dockerfile` which can be used instead of `image`. I know this can be done by parsing my custom CI config, then converting it to use `image` instead of `dockerfile` and finally running the converted CI config as a child pipeline:

```
generate-gitlab-ci-config:
  script: my-gitlab-ci-config-generator.sh > generated-gitlab-ci.yml
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - generated-gitlab-ci.yml

child-pipeline:
  trigger:
    include:
      - artifact: generated-gitlab-ci.yml
        job: generate-gitlab-ci-config
  needs:
    - job: generate-gitlab-ci-config
      artifacts: false
```

Essentially, I need to convert jobs using the custom `dockerfile` property:

```
test.app1:
  dockerfile: ".gitlab-ci/dockerfiles/dynamic-ci/node-gyp-glob-git.Dockerfile"
  variables:
    NPM_WORKSPACE: "apps/app1"
  script:
    - npm -w "${NPM_WORKSPACE}" run test
```

Into two separate jobs like this:

```
build.dynamic-ci-image.node-gyp-glob-git:
  extends: .template.dynamic-ci-image-builder
  variables:
    DOCKERFILE: .gitlab-ci/dockerfiles/dynamic-ci/node-gyp-glob-git.Dockerfile
    
test.app1:
  image: $DYNAMIC_CI_IMAGE
  variables:
    NPM_WORKSPACE: "apps/app1"
  script:
    - npm -w "${NPM_WORKSPACE}" run test
  needs:
    - job: build.dynamic-ci-image.node-gyp-glob-git
      artifacts: true
```

So I end up with one job that builds the `Dockerfile` and another job that uses the dynamically built image.

Here's some pseudo code demonstrating what I'm thinking about doing. Obviously `loadGitlabCiConfig` and `ciConfig.resolveIncludes()` don't exist:

```
const ciConfig = loadGitlabCiConfig("./custom.gitlab-ci.yml")
const ciConfigResolved = ciConfig.resolveIncludes()

const convertedCiConfig = {}

for (const key in ciConfigResolved) {
    const value = ciConfigResolved[key]
    if (key == "dockerfile") {
        const dockerfilePath = value.dockerfile
        const dockerfileName = dockerfilePath.split('/').pop().split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')
        const dockerBuildJobName = "build.dynamic-ci-image." + dockerfileName
        const needsEntry = {
            job: dockerBuildJobName,
            artifacts: true
        }
        const mainJobConfig = {
            ...value,
            .image: "$DYNAMIC_CI_IMAGE",
            needs: value.needs ? [...value.needs, needsEntry] : [needsEntry]
        }
        delete mainJobConfig.dockerfile
        convertedCiConfig[key] = mainJobConfig
        convertedCiConfig[dockerBuildJobName] = {
            extends: ".template.dynamic-ci-image-builder",
            variables: { DOCKERFILE: dockerfilePath }
        }
    }
}
```

Although what I just demonstrated is JavaScript code, I'm not necessarily looking for a JavaScript solution, python or any other language would work for me as well.

**Edit:**
Is there maybe a way to use GitLab's [gitlab_ci_yaml_parser](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/blob/v16.3.0/helpers/gitlab_ci_yaml_parser/parser.go?ref_type=tags) to achieve that? Unfortunately I don't know any `go`.